# Titanium ios contact phone custom labels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I found a bug in Titanium Appcelerator Studio  , the `phone` object return `undefined` when the contact object has custom labels for phone number .

Unfortunately they may take more time to fix this issue , but the good news I can modify the build classes of Objective-C , here is the method to provide person information .

**inside /build/iphone/classes/TiContactsPerson.m**

```
+(NSDictionary*)multiValueLabels
{
    if (multiValueLabels == nil) {
        multiValueLabels = 
            [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(NSString*)kABHomeLabel,@"home", // Generic labels
             kABWorkLabel,@"work",
             kABOtherLabel,@"other",
             kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,@"mobile", // Phone labels
             kABPersonPhonePagerLabel,@"pager",
             kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel,@"workFax",
             kABPersonPhoneMainLabel,@"main",
             kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel,@"iPhone",
             kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel,@"homeFax",
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook,@"facebookProfile",// Social Profile Labels
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFlickr,@"flickrProfile",
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceGameCenter,@"gameCenterProfile",
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceLinkedIn,@"linkedInProfile",
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceMyspace,@"myspaceProfile",
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceSinaWeibo,@"sinaWeiboProfile",
             kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter,@"twitterProfile",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceAIM,@"aim", // IM labels
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceICQ,@"icq",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceJabber,@"jabber",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceMSN,@"msn",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceYahoo,@"yahoo",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceQQ,@"qq",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceSkype,@"skype",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceGoogleTalk,@"googletalk",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceGaduGadu,@"gadugadu",
             kABPersonInstantMessageServiceFacebook,@"facebook",
             kABPersonMotherLabel,@"mother", // Relation labels
             kABPersonFatherLabel,@"father",
             kABPersonParentLabel,@"parent",
             kABPersonSisterLabel,@"sister",
             kABPersonBrotherLabel,@"brother",
             kABPersonChildLabel,@"child",
             kABPersonFriendLabel,@"friend",
             kABPersonSpouseLabel,@"spouse",
             kABPersonPartnerLabel,@"partner",
             kABPersonManagerLabel,@"manager",
             kABPersonAssistantLabel,@"assistant",
             kABPersonAnniversaryLabel,@"anniversary", // Date label
             kABPersonHomePageLabel,@"homepage", // URL label
             nil];
    }
    return multiValueLabels;
}
```

It does not include custom label's set by user for phone number , and that's why the `phone` array return undefined when contact has custom label set.

> my question how to get all custom label's created by user and push
>   them inside above array ?

note : I've reported this bug to appcelerator Jira.

any advice is very much appreciated

Comment: What is the link to the JIRA ticket?

Comment: Jira https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-5730

Comment: OK, I see that it has been reproduced by our testers. Next step is scheduling it.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen sounds good , hope they solve it fast .

Answer (score 0):

The ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19739 is closed and released since SDK 5.1.0